How to make custom UTType with code and use it in SwiftUI?
I have this code below, which I am sure it was working fine some times ago, now the codes does not show any error but I cannot chose my custom file in file importer, where is the issue?
import SwiftUI
import UniformTypeIdentifiers

struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {

        Button("Read xyz project") {
            
            typeGenerator(tag: "xyz", type: { typeValue in

                nsOpenPanelGenerator(nsOpenPanelKind: .runModal, allowedContentTypes: [typeValue], allowsMultipleSelection: false, canChooseDirectories: true, canChooseFiles: true, directoryURL: nil, message: "Select your xyz project", results: { resultURL in
  
                })
                
            })
        }
        
    }
}
            
            

func typeGenerator(tag: String, type: (UTType) -> Void) {
    
    if let unwrappedUTType: UTType = UTType(tag: tag, tagClass: .filenameExtension, conformingTo: .compositeContent) {
        type(unwrappedUTType)
    }
    
}

enum NSOpenPanelKind { case runModal, begin }

func nsOpenPanelGenerator(nsOpenPanelKind: NSOpenPanelKind, allowedContentTypes: [UTType], allowsMultipleSelection: Bool, canChooseDirectories: Bool, canChooseFiles: Bool, directoryURL: URL?, message: String?, results: @escaping ([URL]) -> Void) {
    
    let nsOpenPanel = NSOpenPanel()
    nsOpenPanel.allowedContentTypes = allowedContentTypes
    nsOpenPanel.allowsMultipleSelection = allowsMultipleSelection
    nsOpenPanel.canChooseDirectories = canChooseDirectories
    nsOpenPanel.canChooseFiles = canChooseFiles
    
    if let unwrappedDesktopDirectoryURL: URL = directoryURL {
        nsOpenPanel.directoryURL = unwrappedDesktopDirectoryURL
    }
    
    if let unwrappedMessage: String = message, unwrappedMessage != "" {
        nsOpenPanel.message = unwrappedMessage
    }
    
    switch nsOpenPanelKind {
    case .runModal:
        
        if (nsOpenPanel.runModal() == .OK) {
            results(nsOpenPanel.urls)
        }
        
    case .begin:
        
        nsOpenPanel.begin(completionHandler: { value in
            
            if (value == .OK) { results(nsOpenPanel.urls) }
            
        })
        
    }
    
}

